# GCP - Reaching AppEngine Standard Environment with internal ingress from resources in a shared VPC

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vpc

I have a GCP project where I deployed an AppEngine application. I have set the service's ingress to internal.
In this project i use a shared VPC hosted in another project. This shared VPC is connected to an on-prem environment through an Interconnect.

The problem is that i am not able to reach AppEngine neither from the onprem environment nor a GCE VM instantiated in a subnet of the aforementioned shared VPC.

If anybody could help me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to do this.

I suspect this limitation is because App Engine is not available for VPC Service Controls like other services as [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls) or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings) where a perimeter is needed to reach them, the ingress is `internal` (or `internal + load balancer`) and the service is not in the ***host project***.

For now the workaround is to have the App Engine service in the host project.

On the other hand there is already a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/234341023) to allow requests coming from a resource in a Shared VPC.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I suspected it was a provider's limitation, but from the docs it was not clear: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/application-security

here in the paragraph "Ingress Controls" it looked like it was supposed to be possible to reach app engine through internal ingress even when using a shared VPC.

Thak you again!